# Writing a Win7 x64 filter driver and looking for a place to start

Tags: windows-7, filter, 64-bit, driver

I'm looking to write a filter driver to calibrate the input from a tablet PC Wacom digitiser. As far as I can tell the digitiser is connected via an internal serial port and the protocol is straightforward. So what I need to do is, I think, write a lower filter driver for the serial port, then install it between the Wacom driver and the serial device.

But it's really hard to get started. I downloaded the DDK and I think I've read enough to be able to compile a .sys file (except I've found very little on x64 drivers, but I'm assuming it's pretty much like x86 drivers with some extra compiler switches?) but I'm still lost as to the installation procedure. I know you're supposed to register the driver in the registry, but what's the mechanism by which the PNP system will know where in the stack my driver wants to be attached?

Also, can a filter be temporarily installed by a user-mode application without becoming a permanent part of the driver tree?

I know it's a big topic, so I'm not looking for anyone to guide me through the whole process, but good resources seem to be few and far between. The DDK has little documentation on x64, less still on filter drivers, and it mostly glosses over the details of actually implanting a driver into the stack. Are there any good reads online anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find free samples from Microsoft online, including filter drivers along with the installation files: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware

x64 compilation is indeed very similar to x86, but mind the architecture differences (e.g. different pointer sizes). Also, Win7 x64 drivers are required to be signed as opposed to x86 drivers.

Specifically regarding the instructions to PNP, the information should indeed be in the Inf file, dig it from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549520(v=vs.85).aspx

Regarding your installation question, there is no such thing as temporary installation. The driver, however, won't be loaded if the OS can't bind it to the required interfaces (e.g., lower driver unavailable). You can also disable the filter driver to avoid its loading.

Comment: Ha! Google has failed me, it seems. But that's wonderful. It's a shame about driver signing, though. I thought I read somewhere that there was some setting to allow Win7 x64 to install and run unsigned drivers? That would make development somewhat easier.